# Accessing Depth Buffer in a SubViewport in Godot 4.x

Tags: shader, game-development, godot, godot4

I'm trying to access the depth buffer of a SubViewport, but I'm encountering some issues. The [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/advanced_postprocessing.html#depth-texture) suggests using the following method:

```
uniform sampler2D depth_texture : source_color, hint_depth_texture;
```

This approach works well when reading the depth_texture of the main viewport. But when I use this shader in a SubViewport, it still seems to reference the main viewport's depth buffer instead of the SubViewport to which the mesh is attached. Could someone provide guidance or clarification on how to correctly access the depth buffer of a SubViewport?

The documentation notes that ***accessing the depth texture is only possible when reading from the current viewport and that the depth texture from another viewport cannot be accessed.*** This leads me to believe that accessing the depth buffer in the current SubViewport is feasible. However, I'm unsure how to do this if it's not simply by setting my mesh as a child of the SubViewport.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. If you can make a minimum reproduction project, I suggest posting on https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues